# DataFrame for Large JSON files and POST to API

Tags: python

This is the JSON output that I'm getting from Facebook Graph API.

```
{
"insights": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "day",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 1,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-20T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 0,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Daily Total Impressions",
            "description": "Daily: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "107188788663426/insights/page_impressions/day"
        },
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "week",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 37,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-20T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 37,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "Weekly Total Impressions",
            "description": "Weekly: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "107188788663426/insights/page_impressions/week"
        },
        {
            "name": "page_impressions",
            "period": "days_28",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 37,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-20T07:00:00+0000"
                },
                {
                    "value": 37,
                    "end_time": "2022-05-21T07:00:00+0000"
                }
            ],
            "title": "28 Days Total Impressions",
            "description": "28 Days: The number of times any content from your Page or about your Page entered a person's screen. This includes posts, stories, ads, as well other content or information on your Page. (Total Count)",
            "id": "107188788663426/insights/page_impressions/days_28"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/107188788663426/insights?access_token=EAAQeCPGNpp4BAP1EWQ3eqFPvlFIZCY8xBCCZA3ZAtUcP5w8zDft9pxVr20aZC6IIxyOQObwZBrZCbYnWXzVutCzePHBlnE8r9EFYSrO0xTv1oNKTzY6w7SgYfgC6R4SYSZBgZBVBX2vR36kDnPcSeOdR3QMdVa0MIwu37sCZCRuRpXPUG1QL1hXuCxWu0P6Ei1ZBvjEfAvCTCdJ5zVySNE0OaW&metric=page_impressions&since=1652770800&until=1652943600",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/107188788663426/insights?access_token=EAAQeCPGNpp4BAP1EWQ3eqFPvlFIZCY8xBCCZA3ZAtUcP5w8zDft9pxVr20aZC6IIxyOQObwZBrZCbYnWXzVutCzePHBlnE8r9EFYSrO0xTv1oNKTzY6w7SgYfgC6R4SYSZBgZBVBX2vR36kDnPcSeOdR3QMdVa0MIwu37sCZCRuRpXPUG1QL1hXuCxWu0P6Ei1ZBvjEfAvCTCdJ5zVySNE0OaW&metric=page_impressions&since=1653116400&until=1653289200"
    }
},
"id": "107188788663426"
}
```

The first thing I tried to do is make it more readable by using DataFrame.
Code:

```
parse_json_text = []

for i in profile['insights']['data']:
    parse_json_text.append(i)
pd.DataFrame(parse_json_text).head()
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see from the image values column needs further opening:

```
newDFColumn = dataFrame.loc[:,['values']]
for i in newDFColumn.columns:
    newDFColumn = newDFColumn.explode(i)
newDFColumn.head(9)

newDFFlat = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(newDFColumn.\
                                     to_json(orient="records")))
newDFFlat.head()
```

They give the respective outputs:

[image]
[image]

As you can see this is a lot of coding for only one insight.metric, my project is going to have a lot of them, is there a simpler way of doing everything that I have done. Also I need to post the data to my API (built in .NET Core). The API fields are as follow:

id    (107188788663426)

date

day_impressions

weekly_impressions

28Days_impressions

I want the data to be POST in this format:
[image]

I know this is a very big question, but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of the sample response you have shared? Is it dict or a string. You can check the type using the ```type(your_variable)``` method in python

Comment: @glory9211 its str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using dataframes you can convert the response string into a dictionary to extract fields easily.

```py
import json

raw_data = json.loads(your_raw_string) # parse the string into a python dictionary

useful_data = raw_data['insights']['data'] # Only picking concerned fields

output = {'day' : [], 'week':  [], 'day28': []} # This is where we will store the results as tuples of (value, end_time)

for el in useful_data:
    if el['period'] == 'day':
        for i in el['values']: # Get all items in the values array
            output['day'].append( (i['value'], i['end_time']) )
    
    elif el['period'] == 'week'
        # continue the logic
        pass

print(output)
```

You can read more about the json module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)